# Java POI getHyperlink() throws NotSupportedException

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to copy a spreadsheet containing hyperlinks to another spreadsheet using StreamingCell.

My code is like:

```
private void setCellLinks( Cell destinationCell, Cell sourceCell) {
    Hyperlink oldLink = sourceCell.getHyperlink();
    destinationCell.setHyperlink(oldLink);
}
```

However the sourceCell.getHyperlink() is throwing an exception of:
`com.monitorjbl.xlsx.exceptions.NotSupportedException`

Any idea how can I get the source hyperlink?

Comment: Please read https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader#supported-methods. When using `monitorjbl Excel Streaming Reader` method `Cell.getHyperlink` is not supported. See https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader/blob/af775bab85e873e839c0e36f71c9dfcb830b54b2/src/main/java/com/monitorjbl/xlsx/impl/StreamingCell.java#L478. So you cannot use that streaming reader if it is necessary to get hyperlinks.

Comment: @AxelRichter any idea how can I read the spreadsheet with a different way than  StreamingReader?

Comment: The question is why using that streaming reader instead of using native `apache poi` methods? If `Cell` would be a [org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html), then`Cell.getHyperlink` would be supported.

Comment: I want to merge some excel files into one (with some tabs), therefore I am writing otput file to the cache and after writing all at once